Delayed execution when using bash's trap command?
I use the following .bashrc code to display execution times per command:
ps1_starttime() { PS1_STARTTIME=$EPOCHREALTIME ; }
ps1_duration() { printf "%0.3f" $(bc <<< "$EPOCHREALTIME- $PS1_STARTTIME") ; }
trap "ps1_starttime" DEBUG
export PS1="\`ps1_duration\` \w \\$ "

This works, but I would like to directly inline the ps1_starttime function into the trap statement:
trap 'PS1_STARTTIME=$EPOCHREALTIME' DEBUG

When I do this, $EPOCHREALTIME is evaluated immediately and as a result is not re-evaluated per command as needed.
How to inline the variable assignment directly in trap without the need for an extra function?

Use single quotes ' instead of double quotes " where you don't want immediate evaluation (i.e. the trap).

@pmf Which double quotes are you referring to?

I can't reproduce your problem. Solutions proposed by others work, sure. But no more than yours (I mean, with your second trap. It is not evaluated immediately. Are you sure of the experiment that prompted your question?

Another way to say it is to reply to your question to @pmf : « the ones you didn't even use ». pmf comment would be what to answer if your trial was trap "PS1_STARTTIME=$EPOCHREALTIME" DEBUG. With double quotes, making $EPOCHREALTIME to be evaluated at once. Then answer would be "use simple quotes instead", avoiding immediate evaluation of $EPOCHREALTIME. But thing is you already used simple quotes. So your trap 'PS1_STARTTIME=$EPOCHREALTIME' DEBUG is already working.

Site note, about a thing I discovered testing your code: on my system EPOCHREALTIME is displayed using my locale, so with a comma as decimal separator (that is stupid, IMHO. Those should be only for display purely intended for humans. Unless it is bc that is wrong not to take into account locale to interpret commas as decimal separator. But, well, either way, it fails, because $EPOCHREALTIME contain strings that bc doesn't understand. So, if your intend is to use this not just on your own computer — in which case, you may have some assumption on locale —

it may be necessary to deal with that problem. For example by replacing commas by dots, with ${EPOCHREALTIME//,/.}. Or by temporarily altering LC_ALL, like trap 'LC_ALL=C ; PS1_STARTTIME=$EPOCHREALTIME' DEBUG

Consider using PROMPT_COMMAND instead of PS1 - it's designed to do what you're trying to do with PS1, best I can tell from your question.

It's extremely hard to believe that trap 'PS1_STARTTIME=$EPOCHREALTIME' DEBUG doesn't already do exactly what you want. Are you sure you're using single quotes ' rather than double quotes " in your real code? Please run the following command: printf '#! /bin/bash\nt=17; trap '\''echo $t'\'' EXIT; t=3\n' > ./tst.sh; chmod oug+x ./tst.sh; ./tst.sh and tell us if it outputs 17 or 3. If it's 17 that confirms your problem statement, if it's 3 that refutes your problem statement.

Use a subshell to delay the evaluation of $EPOCHREALTIME. This way, it will be evaluated each time the trap is triggered.
trap 'PS1_STARTTIME=$(echo $EPOCHREALTIME)' DEBUG
export PS1="\$(printf '%0.3f' \$(bc <<< \"\$EPOCHREALTIME - \$PS1_STARTTIME\")) \w \\$ "


I don't get why it would delay it more. Either $ inside the quotes are evaluated immediately, then expression $(echo $EPOCHREALTIME) would, and that is the same as $EPOCHREALTIME. Either it is not (and it is not), and then neither would be '$EPOCHREALTIME'. So, your code works, sure. But it works for the exact same reason why OP's code works already in the first place. Well, I must be missing something in the question and answers, because everybody seems to agree but me. But I don't see the problem, and therefore why your solution solve a problem that I don't see.

Likewise your second line works (doing even better that OP was asking for, sparing 2 functions instead of the 1 they were expecting). But so would have export PS1='$(printf "%0.3f" $(bc <<< "$EPOCHREALTIME - $PS1_STARTTIME")) \w $'. Bottom line begin ' already forbid evaluation of $, and therefore delay them in this case.

@chrslg is correct, the subshell isn't necessary.
